# issubclass(C, Mapping) not behaving as expected

Tags: python, abstract-class

```
from collections import *
class C(object):
    def __iter__(self): pass
    def __contains__(self, i): pass
    def __len__(self): pass
    def __getitem__(self, i): pass
issubclass(C, Mapping) => False
[issubclass(C, cls) for cls in Mapping.__mro__] => [False, True, True, True, True]
```

i.e. C does implement Sized, Iterable and Container.

I would have expected that just as `issubclass(C, Sized)` checks for the presence of a `__len__` method, `issubclass(C, Mapping)` would check for the presence of the three methods required by each immediate superclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collections.Mapping` is a mix-in class that provides the methods `__contains__()`, `keys()`, `items()`, `values()`, `get()`, `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` if you provide definitions of the  methods `__len__()`, `__iter__()` and `__getitem__()`.  For this to work, though, you need to derive from `Mapping`.

If you don't want to derive from `Mapping`, you can also define all of the above-mentioned methods yourself and use

```
Mapping.register(C)
```

to make `issubclass(C, Mapping)` true.

Comment: Interesting, it seems `Mapping` does not implement `__subclasshook__`. Do you know whether there's a reason for that?

Comment: @larsmans: Probably it wasn't considered to useful to check for the mere existence of such a long list of methods.  Checking for a definition of `__len__()` is fine, because a method with this name can only have one meaning.  A class with all of the methods above, on the other hand, doesn't necessarily implement the semantics of a mapping.